# ui-router resolving before a controller not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My state definition looks like:

```
.state('repository', {
  url: '/repository/:host/:owner/:repository',
  views: {
    appView: {
      templateUrl: '/templates/app/repository.html'
    },
    'repositoryView@repository': {
      templateUrl: '/templates/app/_repositoryAnalytics.html'
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    resolvedRepository: [
      '$stateParams', 'RepositoryService', function($stateParams, RepositoryService) {
        console.log(RepositoryService.find($stateParams.host, $stateParams.owner, $stateParams.repository));
        return 1;
      }
    ]
  },
  controller: 'AnalyticsController'
});
```

However, it hands and never gets to the `AnalyticsController`. If I remove the `resolve`, then it works just fine (except, of course, I don't have the resolved value).

I did `return 1` for now just to see if it would return something without worrying about promises. I did the `console.log` to see if it hit, and it does not.

Comment: resolve objects need to return a promise. once this promise resolved you reach to your destination

Comment: Can't I resolve a function value as well? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Comment: And even then, shouldn't it at least log something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created update of the [prvious plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CtAeX4Z0Wnn5QmEpYL20?p=preview). All is working if all the parts are as well. Your **resolve** code is ok (it could really return just a value). **The only thing different is**:

> The **controller** belongs to the view === `{ views : { viewName : { template, controller}}}`

Controller should not (cannot) be defined at the state level. It simply is there to do the MVC stuff...

```
$stateProvider.state('repository', {
  url: '/:host/:owner/:repository',
  views: {
    appView: {
      template: '<div><h1>Repository</h1><div ui-view="repositoryView" ></div>',
      controller: 'AnalyticsController', // here is new position
    }
  },
  // removed from here
  // controller: 'AnalyticsController',
  resolve: { 
    resolvedRepository: [
      '$stateParams', 'RepositoryService', function($stateParams, RepositoryService) {
        console.log(RepositoryService.find($stateParams.host, $stateParams.owner, $stateParams.repository));
        return 1;
      }
    ]
  },
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CtAeX4Z0Wnn5QmEpYL20?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a value for testing purposes, you need to do it in an object, see the first example here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

```
resolve: {
    resolvedRepository: [
        '$stateParams',
        'RepositoryService',
        function($stateParams, RepositoryService) {
            return {'value': 1};
        }
    ]
}
```

If that won't work, try leaving out your RepositoryService to check if that's the problem:

```
resolve: {
    resolvedRepository: [
        '$stateParams',
        function($stateParams) {
            return {'value': 1};
        }
    ]
}
```